Spring Boot 3.2.2 Open Feign Ignoring Retry Period
I am upgrading to Spring Boot 3.2.2.  In my testing I noticed that my Feign Retry is ignoring the period I specify.  It does properly pick up my maxAttempts.  I do have a retryAfter in my Error Decoder when I create the RetryableException, the older RetryableException without this has been deprecated.  I am not sure what impact this has, but I tried putting this at a very high number here as well.  No matter what I seem to do it is ignore and the retry happens every 2 ms.
These are the entries in my POM
        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

       <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <skip.it>true</skip.it>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
       </properties>

      <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
      </dependency>

      <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

This is my Feign Retryer

This is my Error Decoder

This is the logs.  It picks up my retry count of 4 properly, so I know it is finding my Retryer.  It always seems to ignore any number I put in period.

Thank you so much for any help or ideas!!

Pass retryAfter as  null while creating RetryableException.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! "We're a little bit different from other sites."
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. If possible, please [edit] your post to add further details, such as explanations or documentation, so that others can understand how to solve the problem. You can find more information in How do I write a good answer? - "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."  It might be helpful to review some highly upvoted answers as examples to follow. Thanks!

Also check out How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?
and the
Markdown help.
Helpful Hint:  You can click "Edit" under any question or answer to see how it was formatted.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I set the value to Long.MIN_VALUE and it worked.
It looks like this definition is considered in the CalendarDate class as TIME_UNDEFINED = Long.MIN_VALUE;
And this class is accessed when creating a RetryableException.
